# Big O Problem: What if the variable with the largest exponent has negative coefficient?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Here's [an example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example?):
Let f(x) = 6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5, then f(x) is a "big O" of x^4.

Then I swap the coefficients between x^3 and x^4. Now that f(x) = -2x^4 + 6x^3 + 5. Will f(x) still be a "big O" of x^4? I assume not, since f(x) will take less time as x becomes larger. My question is:

What is the big-o complexity of the above equation? At the moment, I'm ignoring -2x^4, which makes f(x) is a "big O" of x^3, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Negative lead coefficients make no sense in big O notation, because [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) says that `f(x) = O(g(x))` means that `|f(x)| <= M * g(x)` for some positive `M` and sufficiently large `x`. The value of `M * g(x)` will be a negative number, but the absolute value `|f(x)|` is never negative. Note that this is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question, so it really belongs on [math.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `-2x^4 + 6x^3 + 5` is still `O(x^4)`, because the leading constant is not part of the big-O expression.  Empirically, it should be clear that as `x` gets arbitrarily large, the `x^3` term will basically become irrelevant.  Whether the `x^4` terms becomes a very large positive or negative number has no bearing on the running time.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O and related asymptotic classes are usually defined in terms of the absolute value of the function, so that it doesn't matter whether it is increasing or decreasing asymptotically.

So it would still be `Theta(x^4)`, which also implies `O(x^4)`.

In context of time complexity analysis this isn't really relevant though, since you cannot have a program/algorithm taking negative time, so the function you are asking about cannot be a function describing the execution time of a program/algorithm.